# Positive definite if and only if determinants are positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $\mathbf{A} = [a_{ij}]$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

I have read that $\mathbf{A}$ is positive-definite if and only if 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11}
\end{vmatrix} > 0\text{, }\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} \\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{vmatrix} > 0\text{, }\begin{vmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix} > 0\text{, } \dots\text{,  etc}.$$
I'd like to prove this statement.

Let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{\mathbf{0}\}$.

Perform induction on $n$. If $n = 1$, this is trivial: $a_{11}\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 > 0 \Longleftrightarrow a_{11} > 0$.

Suppose this is true for $n = k$.

This is where it gets particularly difficult: how do you consider *every* upper left submatrix (as above) of $\mathbf{A}$?

Please avoid using the singular value decomposition or eigendecomposition.

Comment: The proof I like for this statement uses the [Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem), but yes: that uses eigendecomposition in some capacity.

Comment: Instead of making your inductive hypothesis "assume this is true for n = k", make it "assume this is true for all k <= n".

Comment: There are also a proof given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion)

Comment: @florence So, strong induction?

Comment: @Clarinetist Yes, exactly. Strong induction is equivalent to weak induction, but sometimes one is more convenient than the other.

Comment: Well, not *every* submatrix but all the *upper left submatrices* of $A$.

Comment: @Jack Yes, hence I said "as above". I will edit this appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the whole story from the *Linear Algebra and its Applications* (4th edition,  p353) by Gilbert Strang. Your question corresponds to the equivalence of (I) and (III).

To summarize, when proving $(I)\Rightarrow(III)$, you need a clever choice of the vector $x$ in $x^TAx$ such that the upper left submatrix $A_k$ of $A$ will show up.

When proving $(III)\Rightarrow(I)$, you basically exploit the ratio of $\det A_k$ to $\det A_{k-1}$ and its relation to the pivots of [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination).

[image]

[image]

[image]